# font size getting shaky on hover

Tags: css, razor, css-transitions

This my code:

**First**, I want to make the second tex increase more than the first text (the `font-size` of first one could `20px` and the `font-size` of the second one could be `100px`, its just an example.)

**Also** when I use this code the words are "shaking". Can you see this?

How can I do these two things with this code?

Thanks

```css
.ilustration h1 {
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 54px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: transparent;
background-color: green;
}

.ilustration h1:hover {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="ilustration">
      <h1 class="hover_effect">
        First Text <br />
        <span class="cor">Second Text</span>
      </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `transition: transform 1s;` and `transform: scale(1.5);` for smooth transition

> Again the shaky thing depends on multiple factor like, `font-size, font-family` etc.. on hover browser tends to match the dynamic font size, so you have to play around to get the exact match not to get shaky feature.

and

> To have different font size which are within same parent then you can do something like:

```
.ilustration:hover h1 {...}
.ilustration:hover span {...}
```

Below is the answer for both questions:

```css
.ilustration h1 {
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 54px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: transparent;
}

.ilustration:hover h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.ilustration:hover span {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="ilustration">
  <h1 class="hover_effect">
    First Text <br />
    <span class="cor">Second Text</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your time. But the first question? Try to make the second text bigger than the first one?